# Database failed to load WatermelonDB react-native

Tags: ios, reactjs, sqlite, react-native, react-native-ios

I've got an error on react-native :

```
console.error: "[DB] Uh-oh. Database failed to load, we're in big trouble",

{"line":154357,"column":32,"sourceURL":"http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=

ios&dev=true&minify=false"}.
```

[Complete stack trace](https://pastebin.com/mx4zwBjA)

I don't use expo, I do the react-native link (+ test to link manually) but nothing works

Plateform : iOS 12.1, Iphone X on simulator,

Node : 11.4.0

NPM: 6.5.0

react-native-cli: 2.0.1

react-native: 0.57.7

WatermelonDB : 0.9.0

Do you have any idea of how can I debug that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I faced same issue with WatermelonDB one time. It was caused by passing wrong configuration to the dataStore adapter. You may want to check your configuration incase you have same error sometime.

See my case below...

```
import { Database } from '@nozbe/watermelondb';
import SQLiteAdapter from '@nozbe/watermelondb/adapters/sqlite';
import { PostModel } from './Models/PostModel';

import { rootSchema } from './rootSchema';

const adapter = new SQLiteAdapter({
---  rootSchema,  // invalid, what caused error
+++  schema: rootSchema,  // valid configuration 
});

const database = new Database({
  adapter,
  modelClasses: [
    PostModel,

...
```